# Calculate the sample variance, two ways

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

I have a Bernoulli distribution like follows:

$
    Y(X) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        1, & \text{if } 3 \leq x \leq 4\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}
        \end{array}\right\}
$

I know $P(3 \leq X \leq 4) = \frac{7}{15}$, so i can calculate $E[Y(X)] = \frac{7}{15}$ and $Var[Y(X)] = \frac{7}{15} - \frac{7}{15}^2$.

I now want to sample this using $\bar{Y}$ (being an unbiased estimator) of which I want calculate the sample variance. I have two formulas to do so:

1. $S^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(Y_i - \bar{Y})^2}{n-1}$
2. $Var[\bar{Y}] = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$

Intuitively, I would use the second one since I know $\sigma^2$ and don't have any actual samples to put in the formula of the first one. However, when using the second one it suggests that the sample variance is always smaller than the population variance, which doesn't seem to be right.

So I was wondering if this is correct.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by "I now want to *sample this using* $\bar{Y}$"? As for the sample variance being lower than population variance note that $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ is the variance of mean of the sample, which intuitively should also be smaller as now you have many observations from the sample so the mean of a random sample would be closer to actual mean compared to just a single observation.

Comment: Are you sure about *"when using the second one it suggests that the sample variance is always smaller than the population variance"*?  You might try to consider the case where $n=2$ and find the probabilities of the different values of $S^2$